# typeahead.js bloodhound with suggestion engine limit not working shows only 6 records

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

**I want to display all list data typeahead but using following code its display only 6 records on focus in typeahead textbox**

```
var subproduct = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function (d) {

            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.Text);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: SubProductList
});

function subproducttypehead(q, sync) {

    if (q === '') {
        sync(subproduct.all()); // This is the only change needed to get 'ALL' items as the defaults
    } else {
        subproduct.search(q, sync);
    }
}

var typeaheadsub = $('#subproduct');

typeaheadsub
.typeahead({
    minLength: 0,
    highlight: true
},
{ 
    displayKey: 'Text',
    source: subproducttypehead
});



    var subSelectedHandler = function (eventObject, suggestionObject, suggestionDataset) {
        $("#subproduct_id")[0].value=suggestionObject.Value;
    };

    typeaheadsub.on('typeahead:selected', subSelectedHandler);
}
```

How can I display all items from `SubProductList1` in typeahead or autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you...
[Limit problem solved - jsfiddle (click)](https://jsfiddle.net/lalitjisoria/4dboo43a/1/)

```
{
source: subproducttypehead,
limit:9999,
templates: {
empty: [
   '<div class="empty-message">',
   'No match found',
   '</div>'
].join('\n'),
 suggestion: function(query, context){
        return '<div>'+ query.name +'</div><br/>';
 }
```